# update pip from 19.0.1: FileNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, pip

When I execute the command `pip3 install pip` in my terminal, the console returns the following error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (19.0.1)
No metadata found in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/me/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip-19.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'
```

If I test `pip3 install -U pip`, in this case I have this big block:

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/f3/413bab4ff08e1fc4828dfc59996d721917df8e8583ea85385d51125dceff/pip-19.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Error checking for conflicts.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2897, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2691, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2888, in _parsed_pkg_info
    return self._pkg_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2691, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _pkg_info

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 503, in _warn_about_conflicts
    package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py", line 108, in check_install_conflicts
    package_set, _ = create_package_set_from_installed()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py", line 47, in create_package_set_from_installed
    package_set[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2635, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2899, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2908, in _compute_dependencies
    for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2890, in _parsed_pkg_info
    metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1410, in get_metadata
    value = self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1522, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/me/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip-19.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.0.1
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/me/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip-19.0.1.dist-info/RECORD'
```

However, the version given via `pip3 -V` is 19.0.3, but the pip package is marked as still in 19.0.1 in the output of the `pip3 list --outdated` command. I use Python 3.7.2, installed via HomeBrew on my Mac (MacOS 10.14.4).

This error is frequent, the last lines even appearing at each package installation via pip, so I don't know if I should fix it or ignore it. As I don't have this error on my other computers/servers....

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to fix it (thanks to the pip staff on GitHub ^^), by completely remove any python file/folder of my Mac, no matter where they were (with a `find` command in the terminal). Then, when I was sure that python didn't exist anymore, I downloaded it again by using brew.And now everything works fine.

I hope this will help some people if they have the same problem!